# Break or return from always_ff / always_comb

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is it possible to break from always block in Verilog? I have a large block and it will be more readable with breaks, comparing to multiple nested if/else statements.

So I want something like this:

```
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
   ...

   if (x) begin
      ... 
      break;
   end

   ...
end
```

I've found one solution, but it looks like a hack:

```
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
repeat(1) begin

   ...

   if (x) begin
      ... 
      break;
   end

   ...
end
end
```

Comment: is it a synthesizable code or test bench?

Comment: @Serge synthesizable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your code in a function, and use `return` instead of `break`

```
always_ff @(posedge clk) func1;
function void func1;
   if (x) begin
      ... 
      return;
   end

   ...
endfunction
```

This is synthesizable and takes almost the same amount of keystrokes.

Comment: this needs to be verified. synthesis usually associates functions with combinatorial logic. This could cause weird behavior an sim/synt mismatch even if it could be synthesized.

Comment: See http://sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2013-SNUG-SV_Synthesizable-SystemVerilog_paper.pdf section 5.6.2 Void functions

Comment: Also, the fact that `always_ff/comb` looks inside the contents of called functions was put in specifically for synthesis.

Comment: Great idea! Let me fully test it before I accept answer.

Comment: @dave_59 I've checked it for simulation and synthesis. In VCS it works great. But it does not work for Synthesis: Synplify reports an error for non-blocking assignments inside functions. Also if I replace non-blocking with blocking, Synplify generates wrong circuit : it throws away all function-local variables.

Comment: Try declaring all variables outside the function. Also try using task instead of function

Comment: @dave_59 Thanks Dave! When using task instead of function, Synplify allows non-blocking assignment. Declaring variable outside of task prevents Synplify from pruning it. The only problem is that all local variables now leaked into a module scope and I have to rename them to prevent collisions. I will try Design Compiler and Quartus next to check if they accept this code.

Comment: Also it is much harder to debug now, since you don't immediately see which variables are local to process

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you want in a synthesizable code. Also having a large ff block usually means bad verilog programming style in any case. You should try to split the big always block into a number of separate smaller alway_... blocks.

The purpose of synthesizable verilog code is to describe behavior of the hardware which you want to implement. In hardware there are no 'breaks'. Every always_ff block describes a flop, probably with some additional logic. But in general it should look like this:

```
 always_ff @(posedge clk)
      out <= in;
```

if you add more stuff to the block, you have to have a very good reason to do so. Large ff blocks will make people frown.

So, again, you should split your always_ff into a set of flops and combination logic: always_ff and always_comb. This way you will make it more readable and avoid multiple issues which might result from large ff blocks.

Comment: Splitting code will reduce readability in my case. So it's not an option